# Qt serial port does not read the string well

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu, unicode, serial-port

I use Qt 5.4 on Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 LTS to reads a string line from serial port. Everything was OK, but when I re-installed Ubuntu Gnome 14.04 and Qt 5.4, my code of serial port does not work well. When the Arduino send "0" the code of Qt reads it like this "�" and the other numbers that sends over serial the Qt reads it as a letters and symbols. I think the problem with unicode of my Qt. The unicode of my ubuntu is en.US.UTF-8 and the QT unicode is setted to "system". Please help me :(
This is my code that read the data from serial port:

```
    QByteArray input;    
if (serial->canReadLine())    //chect if data line is ready
     input.clear();
   input = serial->readLine(); //read data line from sreial port
   ui->label->setText(input);
   qDebug ()<<input<<endl;
```

this code of Arduino it is working fine with CuteCom and Arduino serial monitor

```
    const int analogInPin = A0; 


unsigned int sensorValue = 0;        // value read from the pot


void setup() {

  Serial.begin(19200);
}

void loop() {
  Serial.print("\n");
  Serial.print("#");
  for (int i=0; i < 5; i++) {
  // read the analog in value:
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);

  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("#");

};
  sensorValue = analogRead(analogInPin);
  Serial.print(sensorValue);
  Serial.print("# \n");  
}
```

Sorry for my English

Comment: Can you please show us the code you use to send the string?

Comment: Please edit your question to add code (or other important and crucial information).

Comment: I edited the post and added the Arduino code :)

Comment: There may be an error of serial port's opening parameters. Check whether your serial port's opening parameters are the same on Arduino and PC.

Comment: As I mentioned before this code was working well before re-installing the Ubuntu. no errors with port opening it is opening the port and read the data.

Comment: Did you modify the default serial port configuration in the old install, and forgot to do it again after the reinstall? Or do you explicitly set the parameters in the receiving program? You didn't yank at the cable between the systems causing some connection troubles? You are 100% sure no code has changed?

Comment: Thanks friend for your replay. I didn't change anything and the cable and everything work fine, I test the Arduino with CuteCom and arduino serial moniter it's working without any problem :(

Comment: I recieved this line with CuteCom and arduino serial monitor "#256#1023#1023#967#891#133# ", as expected.

Comment: @QudorEng, What does "QT unicode is setted to "system" mean? Don't you mean "default file encoding of source files" in Qt Creator ?

Comment: thank you very much friend I am grateful to you, the problem was just the boudrate not correct my be deleted without my knowledge. I will chek this problem as solved :)

Comment: @Qudor I moved my comment into an answer so you can mark it as valid when you're sure it's the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the parity or data/stop bit parameters are different you can still write and read, but you get "funny" output similar to the one you showed us above, and this is not a problem of the unicode setting (especially not with '0', which is a character of the ASCII set).

Try setting the same port parameters explicitly on both ends just before starting the communication.

Comment: Thank you, yes the Baud Rate was different.

Answer (score 0):

There are several problems:

1. You didn't post enough code to know the context of how you use it. I'm assuming that you handle the data in a method attached to the `readyRead` signal.
2. You are only reading one line, where you should be reading lines until no more are available. The `readyRead` signal can be emitted with *any* number of bytes available for reading: these may make up no complete lines, or several complete lines! If you don't keep on reading lines until no more are available, you'll be severely lagging behind incoming data.
3. You are using implicit `QByteArray` to `QString` conversions. These are a bad code smell. Be explicit about it.
4. You have fairly verbose code. You don't need to clear a `QByteArray` before setting its value. You also should declare it at the point of use. Better yet, use type inference that C++11 brought.

Thus:

```
class MyWindow : public QDialog {
  QSerialPort m_port;
  void onData() {
    while (m_port->canReadLine())
      auto input = QString::fromLatin1(m_port->readLine());
      ui->label->setText(input);
      qDebug() << input;
    }
  }
  ...
public:
  MyWindow(QWidget * parent = 0) : QDialog(parent) {
    ...
    connect(&m_port, &QIODevice::readyRead, this, &MyWindow::onData);
  }
};
```